# Function separating an open set from its complement

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Here's the statement that I think is generally true:

> Let the topological space $X$ be compact and Hausdorff, and let $U \subset X$ be a non-empty open set.  Then there exists a continuous $\varphi:X \to \Bbb C$ (or $\Bbb R$ if you prefer) such that $\varphi|_{X \setminus U} = 0$, but $\varphi$ is not identically zero over $X$.

It's clear that this should hold in a metric space.  In particular, we could simply define
$$
\varphi(x) = \max_{y \in X \setminus U} d(x,y)
$$
where we note that the max is attained since $X \setminus U$ is a compact subset.  However, this definition obviously doesn't directly generalize.  So, is the statement true in general?  And, if so, how can it be proven?

If it fails to be true in general, then how can I prove that it holds if $X$ is the set of bounded and multiplicative linear functionals over $\ell^\infty$ with the weak topology (which is indeed both compact and Hausdorff)?

Comment: For my particular example at the end, I suspect that the function
$$
\varphi(\rho) = \inf_{\sigma \in X \setminus U}\sup_{\|f\|_{\infty} = 1} |\rho(f) - \sigma(f)|
$$
will do the trick, but I'd like to avoid this messy construction if it's at all possible.

Comment: Compact Hausdorff spaces are metrizable.

Comment: @JackyChong good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$U\neq \emptyset$, so take $x\in U$.  Then because $X$ is Hausdorff, we know $\{x\}$ is closed. Moreover, $X\setminus U$ is closed.  Being compact and Hausdorff implies that $X$ is normal, so now apply Urysohn Lemma to $X\setminus U $ and $\{x\}$, giving a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$ such that $f[X\setminus U]=\{0\}$ and $f[\{x\}]=\{1\}$, so in particular $f$ is not identically $0$ over $X$.